# Find all the trigonometric functions given a point $(1/3, -2\sqrt2/3)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I get the concepts about all six $(\sin, \cos, \tan, \csc, \sec, \cot$). I'm just having trouble simplifying $\csc$ since I get $\frac{-3}{2\sqrt2}$, so how do i simplify??
Also, same for $\cot(t)$??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To "simplify" $-\dfrac{3}{2\sqrt{2}}$, multiply top and bottom by $\sqrt{2}$.

**Remark:** In the bad old days, multiplication by a complicated number like $\sqrt{2}$ was unpleasant, and division by $\sqrt{2}$ was **very** unpleasant. So one automatically tried, if possible, to make denominators "nice." Note that with a calculator, your original form can be evaluated to high accuracy just as easily as the "simplified" form.

Comment: Can you show me how to work it out?

Comment: We get $-\dfrac{3}{2\sqrt{2}}\cdot\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2}}=-\dfrac{3\sqrt{2}}{4}$.

Comment: Greatly appreciated, thank you! :)

Comment: You are welcome. Now I am sure you can do $\cot$.

Comment: Just to make sure, since tan(t): - 2sqrt2. Cot(t): - 1/2sqrt2 * sqrt2/sqrt2 = - sqrt2/4, correct?

Comment: Yes, that's right, it is $-\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{4}$.